# 400 (Bad Request) Second Time When Posting to API

Tags: node.js, request

Currently, I have run into an issue that I've been stuck on all day. In essence, I am trying to get a login session for an account through the Roblox authentication API. It works the first when I post from my server to their API so that I can get the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` which needs to be set in the headers for the next time I make a post to the same API so I am able to get the `.ROBLOSECURITY` which is used to authenticate that the account session. However, the second time I post to their API with the token in the header, I get a 400 error and I am unsure of why this is occurring.

Also, for anyone who is wondering, it is returning a valid X-CSRF-TOKEN.

```
var request = require('request');

var loginOptions    = {
    url: 'https://auth.roblox.com/v2/login',

    form: {
       'ctype':    'Username',
        'cvalue':   'AccountUsernameHere',
        'password': 'AccountPassGoesHere'
    },

    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

request.post(loginOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    loginOptions.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = response.headers['x-csrf-token'];

    request.post(loginOptions, function(error, response, body) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('Success: ' + body);
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode + ' : ' + response.statusMessage);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there were two issues with my code.

The first issue is that I was using `form` when I should have been using `body`. I also ended up needing to add `json: true` too.

Answer (score 0):

You need install cors in nodejs: npm install cors, you can try the following below

```html
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
 
app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
 
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```